# Storing users input into two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I am going to prompt the user to enter their street name (is a single word) and separated by a space, their house number. The user will give me 10 of these at the prompt.

I am going to put the street name into one array, and the house number into another. So far I have the code shown below. It results in a segmentation fault. I have read all of my notes and I am still unsure why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated. (Note, the second loop was to see if the street  array was correctly storing its elements).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    char *street[10]; 
    int *number[10]; 

    int i;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){


        printf("Enter street and number: \n");


        scanf(" %s %d", street[i], number[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){

        printf("%s ",street[i]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C needs 2-dimensional array for storing strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char street[10][100]; 
    int number[10]; 

    int i;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++){


        printf("Enter street and number: \n");
        scanf("%99s %d", &street[i], &number[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf("%s ",street[i]);
    }
}
```

or with pointers, you could use malloc to allocate memory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *street[10]; 
    int number[10]; 
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<3;i++){
        street[i] = malloc(100);
        printf("Enter street and number: \n");
        scanf("%99s %d", street[i], &number[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        printf("%s ",street[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angela, you have mainly made **3** mistakes in your code .

*First* to have an integer array of 10 elements  `int number[10];` not  `int *number[10];` .Here you need only a one dimensional array. `int *number[10];` Is used for two dimensional array.

*Second* you cannot use string pointer without allocating memory for that.so the allocation code using *malloc*  `street[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);` should be used before reading some values to `street[i]`.

Third while scanning an integer array in c you have to use the `&` operator.So the `scanf` statement should be  `scanf("%s%d", street[i], &number[i]);`

Please try this modified code.This will work:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    char *street[10];
    int number[10];                                     // not *number[10]
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        printf("Enter street and number: \n");
        street[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); // assuming the max-string size is 100
        scanf("%s%d", street[i], &number[i]);           // not number[i]
        getchar();                                      // for handling un managed '\n' (enter-keys)
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        printf("%s\n", street[i]);
    }
}
```